# IBM Rational Application Developer Data Source Explorer DB2 - how to view tables by system name?

Tags: eclipse, db2, ibm-rad

We have a db2 database at our company, and I'm trying to view tables in a schema by their shorter system name instead of by their long name.  Is there any way to do this?  If I'm in the SQL editor, i can get the short/system name to autofill for table names, but they won't show up in the data source explorer.

Sometimes I'm given a table to look up, and I don't know what the long name of the table is, so I can't find it.  The search feature doesn't seem to find it, and the filter options don't find it either.

Any ideas?

Comment: swapped the ibm-rad tag for the ibm tag to get this question to a more appropriate audience

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used RAD, but there's always the [`SYSIBM.SYSTABLES` catalog view](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsystablestable.htm).

I'm guessing by the "short name" you actually mean the tablespace of that table, which can be found on the catalog view like so (`TYPE = 'T'` will only return base tables):

```
SELECT RTRIM(CREATOR) || '.' || RTRIM(NAME)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES
WHERE TSNAME = 'short_name'
  AND TYPE   = 'T'
```

Usually, unless you specify an existing tablespace, DB2 will implicitly create a new tablespace for that table, so it is possible that more than one table will be in a tablespace.  Check the [`CREATE TABLE`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createtable.htm) entry under `IN DATABASE` for more info.